# How can I check if some specific cycles are in a graph?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, graphs-and-networks

How can I check if some specific cycles are in a graph?

```
myGraph = 
  Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
    3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
    5 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 
    6 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5}, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name"];
myCycles = {{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
   5 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}, {2 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
   4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}}
```

I tried the FindCycle and then check if a given cycle is in the FindCycle.
Also is there any simpler method without having to find all cycles in a graph and them check if a cycle is there?
This method would work but I wonder if the graph cycle is large then this would be slow.

Comment: If you do `FindFundamentalCycles[myGraph]` you get the output `{{6 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
  5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6}, {5 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 
  1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
  3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5}, {4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
  5 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3,
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4}}`. Is this what you were going for or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 nope, for example I was given a graph `myGraph` and some  cycles `myCycles`. Now I want to check if cycles in `myCycles` exist in  `myGraph` or not. For example I have a function like `checkCycle[myGraph, myCycles]` and I expect the result in this case is `{True, True}`. The length of `myCycles` can be one or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[subgraphQ]
subgraphQ[g_] := Apply[And] @* Map[EdgeQ[g, #] &]

subgraphQ[myGraph] /@ myCycles
```

> {True, True}

Also

```
ClearAll[subgraphQ2]
subgraphQ2[g_] := AllTrue[#, EdgeQ[g, #] &] &

subgraphQ2[myGraph] /@ myCycles
```

> ```
> {True, True}
> ```

Comment: That is clever. If you want to check two nodes in a graph are connected or not what would you use?

Comment: @hana, `connectedQ[g_,v1_,v2_]:=MemberQ[AdjacencyList[g,v1], v2]`?

Comment: This is simple but not actually work for all cases. Some graphs with two nodes connected but via a long path with many nodes.

Comment: oh, just replace `AdjacencyList` with `VertexComponent`

Comment: Thanks, that works well.